# Hibernate: How to set the length of integer fields

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an entity mapped by hibernate to a MySQL database with some integer fields, e.g.:

```
@Column(name = "BVE_YEAR", nullable = true, length = 4)
private Integer year;
```

The tables are created automatically by Hibernate (`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`)

All fields of type `Integer` or `int` are created with a length of 10, regardless what I specified within the `@Column` annotation.

How can I set the length of the column (except for some `ALTER TABLE` script)?

Thanks in advance for any help and ideas

Comment: @nachokk It has unfortunately no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like chrylis said, the shown length is not of any importance. If you need a 'smaller' type, you can use `TINYINT` in mysql.

I suggest to create production-databases not using some hibernate-automatic, but rather use some SQL-Script.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `@Column` annotation with `precision` and `scale` attributes.

`length` attribute affects only string properties.

You can find more info i.e. [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property), in chapter 2.2.2.3. Declaring column attributes.

If it does not work, you could try `@Min` and `@Max` pr `@Range` annotations of hibernate validator.

Comment: Did you try @Min and @Max?

Comment: I do not have that annotiations. Which maven package do I have to add to get them?

Comment: I don't know yet how to format commets so I can copy it nicely, but this one should be ok (don't have environment to check it on this computer, thus 'should') http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.1.Final

Comment: Thanks, I got them. But they have no affect on the column length.

Comment: I don't have environment set up here, and I don't want to write any sugestions without testing them first, so I'll try to get back to this tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Hmm, I've just run some tests, `scale` and `precision` didn't worked for me neither, however `@Max` annotation worked fine. Tested on hibernate-validator 3.1

Comment: Which RDMS and which client-library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[(Optional) The column length. (Applies only if a string-valued column is used.)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#length%28%29)

If you really want to explicitly set the column width, you'll have to use `columnDefinition` and manually specify the whole thing. Is there a particular reason you want a narrower column that `@Min` wouldn't be clearer for?

Comment: `columnDefinition` works, but it is not what I wanted. (It is to database-specific)

Comment: What do you mean by _"Is there a particular reason you want a narrower column that @Min wouldn't be clearer for?"_

Comment: Why are you wanting to restrict the column width to 4? How does that help you?

Comment: The table will contain bilions of datasets and I do not want to waste space.

Comment: I don't think you're familiar with how the data storage actually works. `Integer` will get mapped to a MySQL `INT`/`INTEGER` type, which takes exactly 4 bytes, period, regardless of how large a value is stored in it.

Comment: Okay. What is the meaning of the length of an column of type "INTEGER"?

Comment: Are you asking about in MySQL or in Hibernate? In Hibernate, it has no meaning at all, as per the spec I quoted. For MySQL, [M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. The maximum legal display width is 255. Display width is unrelated to the range of values a type can contain.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)